# uploading and reading the text file jsp

Tags: jsp

I have found the following code to upload a file in `jsp`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>File Uploading Form</title>
   </head>

   <body>
       <h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />

     <input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" />
     <br />

   </body>

</html>
```

I want to read the uploaded text file here line by line which has the data saved like the following

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and save this data to a string array. I cannot keep the uploaded file and save it on the server so just would like to read it here and destroy. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code you find above is not complete, you have to enclosed the `<input ‘file’ ... >` field into an HTML `<form... action=... >` tag.

This allow to select a local file in your browser, but you need to send it to a special action on the server to list the content of the file.

You can find a full explained upload example on this page: [JSP File Upload & File Download Program Examples](https://www.guru99.com/jsp-file-upload-download.html). Rem: the example in “ Uploading_1.jsp”  is similar to yours, you just need to copy the code in the Servlet “Guru_upload.java” to make it works.